# Redirect MVC Action to Identity server 4 login page manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I installed Identity Server4 which works fine. I use an application Asp.Net Core MVC as a client application. I have a login action and when the user click the button I want to redirect to the identity server login page but I dont know how to do it:

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
   return <Redirect to identity server4 login page??? How to do?>
}
```

If I add an annotation with Authorized, it does it automatically:

```
[Authorized]
public IActionResult Login()
  => Work fine, it redirect to identity server login page with lots of information passed by url
```

How to do it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return a `ChallengeResult` from the action, using the [`Challenge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.challenge?view=aspnetcore-2.2) convenience method:

```
public IActionResult Login() =>
    Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    });
```

This *challenges* using the default challenge scheme, which has already been set up in your example given that the `[Authorize]` attribute is giving the desired result. The example above also demonstrates how to set the `RedirectUri`.

To learn more about what *challenge* means, see [What exactly does Challenge mean in Asp .Net Core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510015/what-exactly-does-challenge-mean-in-asp-net-core-3/60510376#60510376).