# What exactly does Challenge mean in Asp .Net Core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I know that you can have authentication and authorization in asp .net core. So for example you can deny access to some resources using the Authorize attribute.

So for example if an user tries to access a resource that is not accessible then he might get redirected to the login page.

But I saw that there is a concept called Challenge in asp .net core. I don't know where it fits in all of this. From what I understood, if the user is not logged in it can redirect him to a page where he can log in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is covered in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication#challenge):

> An authentication challenge is invoked by Authorization when an unauthenticated user requests an endpoint that requires authentication. An authentication challenge is issued, for example, when an anonymous user requests a restricted resource or follows a login link. Authorization invokes a challenge using the specified authentication scheme(s), or the default if none is specified. See [ChallengeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync). Authentication challenge examples include:
>
> - A cookie authentication scheme redirecting the user to a login page.
> - A JWT bearer scheme returning a 401 result with a `www-authenticate: bearer` header.
>
> A challenge action should let the user know what authentication mechanism to use to access the requested resource.